# Updating an Element in Razor MVC Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller

My issue is that I'm just trying to replace the text of some divs (changing the wording of some buttons) in a corporate application that's built on Razor MVC, but for some reason I can't target elements that are within the @RenderBody section.  I'm not familiar enough with Razor (didn't know what it was until I started researching this issue) to know why this is.

Normally I would have:

```
<div id="cats">Cats are soft.</div>
```

And if I wanted to change the text to be more correct I would just do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cats").html("Cats can be soft.");
});
```

This all works nicely in the plain html world, but doesn't seem to pick up that there is an ID of "cats".  My understanding is that whatever is in the

```
@section script{ ... }
```

will load when the below line is added:

```
@RenderSection("script", required: false)
```

So that's where I have my current code.  However, no matter where I seem to put my snippet, it doesn't want to fire.  Anything that I have outside of the @RenderBody in the view it seems to find.

If anyone could help that would be really appreciated.

Comment: using the same code in section script should work. any errors in console? might be an error of jquery library .

Comment: no, it's really weird.  What I've noticed is that if I throw an alert('') in there it will fire seemingly before the page content renders, even though it's within the document.ready function.  I've confirmed with dev tools that jquery is loading and no errors (or even warnings for that matter) are being thrown.  The change will fire on any targets outside of the @RenderBody() within my <body></body> tags.

update: I can enter my jquery statement no problem in the console manually after the page has loaded.  This is super bizarre and I can't even show it because it's not public.

Comment: Have you tried window.load function ? try it, this may work. $( window ).load(function() {});

Comment: replace document.,ready with window.load function